# Folder /etc/rc.d was removed from Synology NAS

Tags: network-attached-storage, init.d, etc, rc.d

I was installing the Syncrify package when I created a file to place it in the /etc/rc.d directory, guiding by the following tutorial:
http://web.synametrics.com/syncrifyfreenas.htm
But, when I tried to copy the file... I overwrited the directory !!!!!!

```
cp file /etc/rc.d
```

My init.d directory is empty. I read information about how to restore the init.d directory, but not works for the NAS Synology.

Does anyone know how to solve it?, or please, can anyone send me his directory to copy in my Synology?

Thanks in advance.

**EDITED AND SOLVED:**

It seems very strange that everything works properly, but as I didn't find the real directory...

The real directory was in `/usr/local/etc/rc.d` (in my case, it isn't empty)

I make a symlink with the real directory using

```
ln -s /usr/local/etc/rc.d /etc/
```

Thanks !!!!

Comment: What version of DMS? The latest os 5.2.... Synology does provide telephone tech support - https://www.synology.com/en-us/company/contact_us. Also, after reading Brandon's answer and then checking my Synology NAS running DSM 5.2, I can confirm I have a /usr/local/etc/rc.d directory (it's empty) but I don't have a /etc/rc.d directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless something is very, very wrong with your system, that should have been a harmless copy command.  Are you *certain* /etc/rc.d is the actual location of your startup scripts?  Doing some quick googling seems to return a lot of results for potential rc.d locations such as /usr/local/etc/rc.d

The only possible way I can imagine that command could have damaged your system would be if /etc/rc.d was a symbolic link to the real rc.d directory.  Even then, it should have worked.  If this is the case, then this should fix it:

```
ln -s /path/to/real/rc.d /etc/rc.d
```